# Remove empty space

Tags: php, html, css

With the php script below I read user-records of my sql database and show them in my webpage. However, there is an unwanted empty space between the records. How can I remove this empty space?
Sorry, the items are in Dutch language.

````
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 11px;
} 
th,td {
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
    cell-padding: 0px;
}
table.a {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 350px; 
  background-color: lightblue; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  font-size: 13px; 
}
table.b {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 350px;
}
table.c {
  width: 80px;
  margin-left: 355px;
  top: -105px;
  position: relative;
}
</style>

foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo    "<table class=a><tr>" . 
        "<td>" . $row['achternaam'] . "</td>" . 
        "<td>" . $row['tussenvgsl'] . "</td>" . 
        "<td>" . $row['voornaam'] . "</td>" . 
        "<td>" . $row['stem'] . "</td>" .
        "</tr></table>";
    echo    "<table class=b><tr><td>" .
        $row['straat'] . "</td><td>" . "</td></tr></table>";
    echo    "<table class=b><tr><td>" . 
        $row['woonplaats'] . "</td><td>" . 
        $row['postcode'] . "</td></tr></table>";
    echo    "<table class=b><tr><td>" .
        "Tel: " . $row['telefoon'] . "</td></tr></table>"; 
    echo    "<table class=b><tr><td>" .
        "Email: " . $row['email'] . "</td></tr></table>";
    echo    "<table class=b><tr><td>" .
        "Geb. datum: " . date('d-m-Y',($row['geboortedatum'])) . "</td><td>" .
        "Inschrijfdatum: " . date('d-m-Y',($row['inschrijfdatum'])) . "</td></table>" ;
    echo    "<table class=c><tr>" . 
        "<td >" . "<img src='".$row['foto']." ' width=80  >"  . "</td>" .
        "</tr></table>";```
````

Comment: typo error `class=c` to `class='c'`

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? It would be easier to reproduce your problem if you showed the generated markup and removed the PHP tag - unless that makes a difference here?

Answer (score 1):

The empty space is because of the position: relative; declared in table.c. You can try to declare like this:

```
`table.c {
  width: 80px;
  margin-left: 355px;
  top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}`
```

This should remove the empty space.

Comment: The empty space is added as soon as I add the img statement. If I change position from relative to absolute the empty-space disappears but all photos are displayed on the same position.

Comment: Since you need to place this absolute to something I would suggest removing the table with the image and moving it inside the first table inside a <span> tag with something like: echo    "<table class=a><tr>" . "<td><span class='c'><img src='".$row['foto']." ' width=80  >" . $row['achternaam'] . "</td>" .

Comment: When I do this, the image is placed in the first row. However, this row will then be as high as the height of the photo. That's not my intention.
I want to place the image to the right of the text rows and as high as these 6 rows together.

Comment: You can achieve this multiple ways, either adding a new column to the table or via CSS float property. Also as this is not PHP related you can remove the PHP tag.